# Creating an increment method without an instance/static variable?

Tags: java

We can have an increment method like:

```
private static int id = 1;

public static int generateId() {
  return id++;
}
```

But is it possible to implement `generateId` without having the `id` variable so that it doesn't distract readers of the class? So that everything is contained in the method

Comment: "doesn't distract readers of the class" - you've already made it private

Comment: No, it isn't possible to do it another way.  But it shouldn't be `static` anyway: it should be a class `IdProvider` or the like that gets passed around to everything that needs an ID.

Comment: You could save the id to a database or txt file...

Comment: Also the naming of `id` as a static variable is very confusing. Perhaps `autoIncrementId`, `nextGeneratedId`, or something to suggest it's the value to increment would be clearer to the reader. Otherwise one may assume it's the id of the instance.

Comment: @brso05 I'd love to know how you'd do that in a less distracting way than that variable declaration.

Comment: Any auto increment must have some way of remembering what that last value was. That is it must have a memory. You can't do it without it.

Comment: @AndyTurner "`So that everything is contained in the method`"...

Comment: I don't need it to be a robust solution since it's used for internal testing purposes. I think `IdProvider` would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to create everything contained in the method provided you allow a parameter to be passed in. And then construct an algorithm in the method that uses current time to compute the id.